# I just can't use social engeneering tool in kali

Tags: kali-linux

I'm doing an information security course, but one the main tools isn't working, I can't learn how to clone a site like this, look...
It keeps asking me to copy all the content inside www directory to the folder html in itself, and, when I do it, I find myself with the same error message, is Kali having some issues or something?
Btw, I'm new using Kali.[image]

Comment: Your problem is not with Kali but with this tool. Could you edit your question to focus on this tool and not the OS?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, as a matter of fact, I was typing www.facebook.com and I forgot the http://, facebook login page is a .jsp extension file not a .html file and wasn't even considering that. I've solved my problem. Sorry actually, my deal is between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saying that the contents of the website you targeted has been cloned to /var/www/.

On **some** webserver configurations the document root begins at /var/www/html/ instead of /var/www/.   Check your environement variables and look for the value of DOCUMENT_ROOT

You can list your environment variables by running

```
cat /proc/self/environ
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, as a matter of fact, I was typing www.facebook.com and I forgot the http://, facebook login page is a .jsp extension file not a .html file and wasn't even considering that. I've solved my problem. Thank you again.